# Video on demand streaming for Gentoo ppc64

Tags: gentoo, streaming, video-streaming

I want to setup a vod streaming server on my ppc64 Gentoo.

It should be able to :

- Work headless.
- Stream to iPhone, MacOS and if possible to Linux (rtsp protocol ?).
- Stream different formats like avi or mp4.
- Work for a small number of clients (max ~10).
- Preferably, work without user interaction once correctly setup (don't have to manually add new files to stream)

I already tried Darwin Streaming Server, but it can only stream mov or mp4 and I don't want to convert every files.

I also installed VLC, but it doesn't seem to work properly (can't launch telnet interface, …).

What is the best choice ?

Answer (score 0):

Flash Streaming Server and Red5 can pretty much do everything you've asked for, with the exception of "Stream to iPhone, MacOS and if possible to Linux (rtsp protocol ?)". The application that you stream to is independant of the streaming server, but red5 and FMS both support RTSP and ERTSP.